# What to do if a contract does not support ERC165?

Tags: solidity, validators, eip, erc165

I have this code...

```
            try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd) returns (bool supported721) {
                require(!supported721, "!TokenType");
                try IERC165(_token.assetContract).supportsInterface(0xd9b67a26) returns (bool supported1155) {
                    require(!supported1155, "!TokenType");
                } catch Error(string memory) {}
            } catch Error(string memory) {}
```

and a contract that does not implement `ERC165`.

How can I modify the code so it does not fail when it tries to run the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the contract breaking, you could delete the `require()`statement and change to something like:

```
if (supported721) then {
//do if is supported
} else {
// do if is not supported
}
```

Hope it helps